# Create .editorconfig file based on existing repository

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

We have an existing solution with about 40 .NET Core 2.2 C# projects (ASP.NET Core, regular class libraries, xUnit projects). We want to streamline our conventions using the new EditorConfig standard, and include an `.editorconfig` file with `dotnet_` and `csharp_` rules.

I'd take something similar to [the recommended example from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2019#example-editorconfig-file), but coming from most people using Resharper with some custom settings, there will be a decent sized gap between our existing code and the example editorconfig. - We now have a mix of JetBrains Rider and Visual Studio 2019 (with or without Resharper).

Is there a way to "extract" an editorconfig with dotnet and csharp rules from an existing codebase, minimizing the number of initial violations?